# Find the name of the column in a Pandas DF which contains the longest list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a Pandas DataFrame with lists stored in several of the columns, is there a simple way to find the column name which contains the longest list for each row?

For example, with this data:

```
                          positive                 negative          neutral
1   [marvel, moral, bold, destiny]                       []   [view, should]
2                      [beautiful]      [complicated, need]               []
3                      [celebrate]   [crippling, addiction]            [big]
```

I want to identify "positive" as the column with the longest list for row 1 and "negative" for rows 2 and 3.

I thought I could use `str.len()` to calculate the list lengths and `idmax()` to get the column names, but can't figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [227]: df.applymap(len).idxmax(axis=1)
Out[227]:
0    positive
1    negative
2    negative
dtype: object
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! Quick follow-up: `idxmax()` returns the first index (ie 'positive') when 'positive', 'negative' and 'neutral' are all empty lists. Could this solution be modified to ignore such rows? I've tried replacing the empty lists with NaNs, but `len` then complains: `"object of type 'float' has no len()"`.

Comment: @user2950747, could you provide a reproducible data set?

Comment: [this sample data](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9dcf95cd39fa09eec291085eafecbd0c/polarity.csv) has empty lists in the 3rd row from the end, and would be labelled 'positive' by `idxmax()`.

Comment: @user2950747, do you simply want to drop such rows?

Comment: ah... Yes! I wasn't thinking of it like that, but that would be the simplest approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: row.apply(len).argmax(), axis=1)
0    positive
1    negative
2    negative
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this ...

```
df=df.reset_index()
DF=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['index'])
DF['Length']=DF['value'].apply(lambda x : len(x))
DF.sort_values(['index','Length']).drop_duplicates(subset=['index'],keep='last')
```