# How do you read in a dataframe with lists using pd.read_clipboard?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, clipboard

Here's some data from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827199/find-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-pandas-df-which-contains-the-longest-list/45827215):

```
                          positive                 negative          neutral
1   [marvel, moral, bold, destiny]                       []   [view, should]
2                      [beautiful]      [complicated, need]               []
3                      [celebrate]   [crippling, addiction]            [big]
```

What I would do first is to add quotes across all words, and then:

```
import ast

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}')
df = df.applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Lists of strings

For basic structures you can use [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931531/2285236) without having to add quotes:

```
import yaml
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}').applymap(yaml.load)

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
Out: list
```

---

#### Lists of numeric data

Under certain conditions, you can read your lists as strings and the convert them using `literal_eval` (or `pd.eval`, if they are simple lists).

For example,

```
           A   B
0  [1, 2, 3]  11
1  [4, 5, 6]  12
```

First, ensure there are at least two spaces between the columns, then copy your data and run the following:

```
import ast 

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python')
df['A'] = df['A'].map(ast.literal_eval)    
df
    
           A   B
0  [1, 2, 3]  11
1  [4, 5, 6]  12

df.dtypes

A    object
B     int64
dtype: object
```

> **Notes**
>
> - for multiple columns, use `applymap` in the conversion step:
>
>   ```
>   df[['A', 'B', ...]] = df[['A', 'B', ...]].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
>   ```
> - if your columns can contain NaNs, define a function that can handle them appropriately:
>
>   ```
>   parser = lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else ast.literal_eval(x)
>   df[['A', 'B', ...]] = df[['A', 'B', ...]].applymap(parser)
>   ```
> - if your columns contain lists of strings, you will need something like `yaml.load` (requires installation) to parse them instead if you don't want to manually add
>   quotes to the data. See above.

Comment: I think the import is a small price to pay for having a solution this bullet-proof. As long as it's builtin, it's fine. All the other answers were wonderful, but I accept this one in particular because of its simplicity.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: yaml is not built-in, the library needs to be pip installed. Apologies for the misinfo!

Answer (score 8):

I did it this way:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[\[\]]*', '').str.split(',\s*', expand=False))
```

PS i'm sure - there must be a better way to do that...

Comment: Better than this way: `df = pd.DataFrame({'positive': [['marvel', 'moral', 'bold', 'destiny'], ['beutiful'], ['celebrate']], 'negative': [[], ['complicated', 'need'], ['crippling', 'addiction']], 'neutral': [['view', 'should'], [], ['big']]})`...

Comment: For small snippets, `df.applymap(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(', '))` might also work (but does not handle spaces as robustly as MaxU's answer.)

Comment: @unutbu, it looks good - would you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is

```
In [43]:  df.applymap(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(', '))
Out[43]: 
                         positive                negative         neutral
1  [marvel, moral, bold, destiny]                      []  [view, should]
2                     [beautiful]     [complicated, need]              []
3                     [celebrate]  [crippling, addiction]           [big]
```

Note that this assumes the first and last character in each cell is `[` and `]`.
It also assumes there is exactly one space after the commas.

Answer (score 5):

Another version:

```
df.applymap(lambda x:
            ast.literal_eval("[" + re.sub(r"[[\]]", "'", 
                                          re.sub("[,\s]+", "','", x)) + "]"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Per help from @MaxU

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

Then:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str[1:-1].str.split(', '))
                         positive                negative         neutral
1  [marvel, moral, bold, destiny]                      []  [view, should]
2                     [beautiful]     [complicated, need]              []
3                     [celebrate]  [crippling, addiction]           [big]

>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str[1:-1].str.split()).loc[3, 'negative']
['crippling', 'addiction']
```

And per the notes from @unutbu who came up with a similar solution:

> assumes the first and last character in each cell is [ and ]. It also assumes there is exactly one space after the commas.