# AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis', using pandas eval

Tags: python, pandas, eval, apply

I have a series of the form:

```
s

0    [133, 115, 3, 1]
1    [114, 115, 2, 3]
2      [51, 59, 1, 1]
dtype: object
```

Note that its elements are *strings*:

```
s[0]
'[133, 115, 3, 1]'
```

I'm trying to use `pd.eval` to parse this string into a column of lists. This works for this sample data.

```
pd.eval(s)

array([[133, 115, 3, 1],
       [114, 115, 2, 3],
       [51, 59, 1, 1]], dtype=object)
```

However, on much larger data (order of 10K), this fails miserably!

```
len(s)
300000

pd.eval(s)
AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'
```

What am I missing here? Is there something wrong with the function or my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is fine, and `pandas.eval` is buggy, but not in the way you think. There is a hint [in the relevant github issue page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16289#issuecomment-300042717) that urged me to take a closer look [at the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html).

```
pandas.eval(expr, parser='pandas', engine=None, truediv=True, local_dict=None,
            global_dict=None, resolvers=(), level=0, target=None, inplace=False)

    Evaluate a Python expression as a string using various backends.

    Parameters:
        expr: str or unicode
            The expression to evaluate. This string cannot contain any Python
            statements, only Python expressions.
        [...]
```

As you can see, the documented behaviour is to pass *strings* to `pd.eval`, in line with the general (and expected) behaviour of the `eval`/`exec` class of functions. You pass a string, and end up with an arbitrary object.

As I see it, `pandas.eval` is buggy because it doesn't reject the `Series` input `expr` up front, leading it to guess in the face of ambiguity. The fact that the default shortening of the `Series`' `__repr__` designed for pretty printing can drastically affect your result is the best proof of this situation.

The solution is then to step back from the XY problem, and use [the right tool to convert your data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008192/5067311), and preferably stop using `pandas.eval` for this purpose entirely. Even in the working cases where the `Series` is small, you can't really be sure that future pandas versions don't break this "feature" completely.

Comment: Okay, so you mention an XY problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your answer lists the alternatives, I just wanted to emphasize that instead of waiting on `pd.eval` to be "fixed", one should choose one of those :)

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't pick up on that at first. Thanks for the clarification! Also, I agree with your answer, because the docs don't mention what should be passed and what shouldn't. So, people make the common mistake of assuming that `pd.eval` will work on each string in the series in isolation, rather than the entire series `__repr__` as a whole, which is what it does.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I disagree: the docs are very explicit about `expr` being an `str`/`unicode` instance. There is a remark saying "*`Series` and `DataFrame` objects are supported and behave as they would with plain ol’ Python evaluation*", but that refers to the _contents_ of the string passed. Anything else is wishful thinking :P But the comments in the relevant SO posts suggest that this does trip up users every once in a while, so providing a solution/alternative holds value.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**
This is debattedly a bug in eval. See the open github issue [GH16289](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16289).

---

**Why am I getting this error?**
This is because [`pd.eval`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/computation/eval.py) cannot parse series with more than 100 rows. Here's an example.

```
len(s)
300000

pd.eval(s.head(100))  # returns a parsed result
```

Whereas,

```
pd.eval(s.head(101))
AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'
```

This issue persists, regardless of the parser or the engine.

---

**What does this error mean?**
`pd.eval` operates on the `__repr__` of the Series, rather than the objects contained within it (which is the cause of this bug). The `__repr__` truncated rows, replacing them with a `...` (ellipsis). This ellipsis is misinterpreted by the engine as an `Ellipsis` object -

```
...
Ellipsis

pd.eval('...')
AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'
```

`pd.eval` technically is not supposed to parse series of strings (the documentation mentioned it is meant to receive strings) and (as described by the accepted answer) will try to make a reasonable guess at the result instead of rejecting the input outright.

Whether this is intended behavior or incomplete behavior (a lot of pandas methods operate differently based on the input - and eval could work on a series by mapping itself onto each row, which is how I initially assumed this was working anyway) is up for discussion, since there's an open issue tracking this.

---

**What can I do to make this to work?**
Right now, there isn't a solution (the issue is still open as of 12/28/2017), *however*, there are a couple of workarounds.

**Option 1**
[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
This option should work out of the box if you can guarantee that you do not have any malformed strings.

```
from ast import literal_eval

s.apply(literal_eval)

0    [133, 115, 3, 1]
1    [114, 115, 2, 3]
2      [51, 59, 1, 1]
dtype: object
```

If there is a possibility of malformed data, you'll need to write a little error handling code. You can do that with a function -

```
def safe_parse(x):
    try:
        return literal_eval(x)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        return np.nan # replace with any suitable placeholder value
```

Pass this function to `apply` -

```
s.apply(safe_parse)
    
0    [133, 115, 3, 1]
1    [114, 115, 2, 3]
2      [51, 59, 1, 1]
dtype: object
```

`ast` works for any number of rows, and is slow, but reliable. You can also use `pd.json.loads` for JSON data, applying the same ideas as with `literal_eval`.

**Option 2**
`yaml.load`
Another great option for parsing simple data, I [picked this up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45827519/5741205) from @ayhan a while ago.

```
import yaml
s.apply(yaml.load)

0    [133, 115, 3, 1]
1    [114, 115, 2, 3]
2      [51, 59, 1, 1]
dtype: object
```

I haven't tested this on more complex structures, but this should work for almost any basic string representation of data.

You can find the documentation for PyYAML [here](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). Scroll down a bit and you'll find more details on the `load` function.

---

**Note**

- If you're working with JSON data, it might be suitable to read your file using [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) or [`pd.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to begin with.
- You can also perform parsing as you read in your data, using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) -

  ```
    s = pd.read_csv(converters=literal_eval, squeeze=True)
  ```

  Where the `converters` argument will apply that function passed on the column as it is read, so you don't have to deal with parsing later.
- Continuing the point above, if you're working with a dataframe, pass a `dict` -

  ```
    df =  pd.read_csv(converters={'col' : literal_eval})
  ```

  Where `col` is the column that needs to be parsed
  You can also pass `pd.json.loads` (for json data), or `pd.eval` (if you have 100 rows or less).

---

Credits to MaxU and Moondra for uncovering this issue.

Comment: yeah, i remember that case... ;)

Comment: @MaxU I made sure to credit you and Moondra in the answer. Let me know if I can improve the answer somehow!

Comment: I also liked [@ayhan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45827519/5741205) a lot...

Comment: @MaxU Cheers! Can't believe I didn't remember that one.

Comment: I was never been to this error till today. Nice for pointing it out.

Comment: I have the same problem before , My solution is chunk convert...:-)

Comment: @Wen I understood... you mean iterate in chunks of 100? That did cross my mind last night, I'll add it as another option sometime and do a timing comparison. ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the chunk size can be optimize, the closer to the tolerance the faster :-)