# string vector to list python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word2vec

I'm working in Python and I  have a column in data frame that is a string and looks like that :

```
df['set'] 

0  [911,3040]
1  [130055, 99832, 62131]
2  [19397, 3987, 5330, 14781]
3  [76514, 70178, 70301, 76545]
4  [79185, 38367, 131155, 79433]
```

I would like it to be:

```
['911','3040'],['130055','99832','62131'],['19397','3987','5330','14781'],['76514',70178','70301','76545'],['79185','38367','131155','79433']
```

in order to be able to run Word2Vec:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(df['set'] , size=100)
```

Thanks !

Comment: `df['set'].tolist()`

Comment: Ah, it is a string? In that case, you'll need to convert it first. How many rows do you have? Less than 100?

Comment: So the column is a list of ints and your want a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column of strings, I'd recommend looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008192/4909087) at different ways of parsing it.

Here's how I'd do it, using `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> import ast
>>> [list(map(str, x)) for x in df['set'].apply(ast.literal_eval)]
```

Or, using `pd.eval` -

```
>>> [list(map(str, x)) for x in df['set'].apply(pd.eval)]  # 100 rows or less
```

Or, using `yaml.load` -

```
>>> import yaml
>>> [list(map(str, x)) for x in df['set'].apply(yaml.load)]
```

```
[
     ['911', '3040'], 
     ['130055', '99832', '62131'], 
     ['19397', '3987', '5330', '14781'], 
     ['76514', '70178', '70301', '76545'],
     ['79185', '38367', '131155', '79433']
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec([[str(y) for y in x] for x in df['set']] , size=100)

L = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in df['set']]
print (L)

[['911', '3040'],
 ['130055', '99832', '62131'], 
 ['19397', '3987', '5330', '14781'],
 ['76514', '70178', '70301', '76545'], 
 ['79185', '38367', '131155', '79433']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new column (`str_set`) with the items in the `set` column converted to string:

```
df["str_set"] = [[str(item) for item in df.loc[row, "set"]] for row in range(len(df["set"]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert every single element to a string with a simple list comprehension and overwrite your old column:

```
df['set']  = [[str(i) for i in row] for row in df['set']]
```

Executed on the data provided:

```
data_col = [911,3040], [130055, 99832, 62131], [19397, 3987, 5330, 14781], [76514, 70178, 70301, 76545],[79185, 38367, 131155, 79433]

out = [[str(i) for i in row] for row in data_col]

out

[['911', '3040'],
 ['130055', '99832', '62131'],
 ['19397', '3987', '5330', '14781'],
 ['76514', '70178', '70301', '76545'],
 ['79185', '38367', '131155', '79433']]
```

Not sure if this is the fastest way for a big data set as there are a lot of iterations.

Comment: Sorry, but it is same like my answer :(

Comment: Sorry, just refreshed the page and saw it :(
Voted yours up.

Comment: Ya, I dont want to say you copy my answer, but the best is removed it, because same.