# How to read xlsx file with out loosing data type

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, data-analysis

How to read xlsx file with out loosing data type

Example Data:

```
Column1                                                 Column2         
['&arg_Mode_previousMode', '&arg_Mode_nextMode']        Mode            
['arg_Mode_nextMode']                                   Switch
```

```
df = pd.ExcelFile("DF.xlsx")
df1 = df.parse("DF")
```

the output is return as string , but one of my column has List elements.
when i use df1 in my application its unable to read as List.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us It explains how to convert a column of strings to a column of lists.

Comment: it's converting only one column. I need total data frame conversion in single command line.

Comment: `import ast; df = df.apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use

```
pd.read_excel(..., dtype= {'Column1': np.float64, 'Column1': np.int32}
```

of course specifying the column types wisely