# Why is my series from the DataFrame is giving me individual characters instead of items?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, series

```
cast_name=movies_DataFrame["cast name"]
cast_name[0]
```

> "['Tom Hanks', 'Tim Allen', 'Don Rickles', 'Jim Varney', 'Wallace Shawn', 'John Ratzenberger', 'Annie Potts', 'John Morris', 'Erik von Detten', 'Laurie Metcalf', 'R. Lee Ermey', 'Sarah Freeman', 'Penn Jillette']"

```
 cast_name[0][1]
```

> " ' "

Comment: Because `cast_name[0]` is a string, and not a list

Comment: I suggest seeing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us) for advice on how to cast your data.