# Evaluate string in column of dataframe with a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the following format:

```
Name           Factor     Expression   Year 
Hydro          0.075            <10    2010  
Hydro          0.075            >10    2010  
Hydro          0.075            <10    2011  
Hydro          0.075            >10    2011
Hydro          0.075            <10    2012
```

And the following variable: `i=3`.

I would like to filter the dataframe where the `Expression` column evaluates as true, when the variable `i` is on the left hand side of the string in the column of expression.

For example, the first row would evaluate to true as `3<10`.

The resulting dataframe that I would like is:

```
Name           Factor     Expression   Year 
Hydro          0.075            <10    2010  
Hydro          0.075            <10    2011  
Hydro          0.075            <10    2012
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a [safer version of `eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.eval.html) that supports a limited number of operations.  Luckily, `>` and `<` work, and you can use this along with string concatenation:

```
i = '3'
idx = pd.eval(i + df.Expression)
df.loc[idx]
```

```
    Name  Factor Expression  Year
0  Hydro   0.075        <10  2010
2  Hydro   0.075        <10  2011
4  Hydro   0.075        <10  2012
```

---

As @coldspeed noted, the above approach only works on DataFrames that are `<` 100 rows*, which isn't ideal.  He also proposed the following solution:

```
df[[pd.eval(f"{i}{j}") for j in df['Expression']]]
```

<sub>*The above limitation is discussed more in depth in the following question: [AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis', using pandas eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us)</sub>

Comment: Careful, `pd.eval` will only work if your DataFrame is 100 rows or smaller.

Comment: Hmm, did not know that, really limits things quite a bit

Comment: If you want to generalise to any size, you should use `df[[pd.eval(f"{i}{j}") for j in df['Expression']]]` instead.

Comment: @coldspeed do you know where that limitation is documented? I just get an attribute error when it reaches that size and I don't see it in the documentation

Comment: Yes! It is documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us