# Iterate pandas data frame for rows consists of arrays and compute a moving average based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out a problem I am trying to solve.
I have a pandas data frame coming from this:

```
date,       id,     measure,    result
2016-07-11, 31, "[2, 5, 3, 3]",     1
2016-07-12, 32, "[3, 5, 3, 3]",     1
2016-07-13, 33, "[2, 1, 2, 2]",     1
2016-07-14, 34, "[2, 6, 3, 3]",     1
2016-07-15, 35, "[39, 31, 73, 34]", 0
2016-07-16, 36, "[3, 2, 3, 3]",     1
2016-07-17, 37, "[3, 8, 3, 3]",     1
```

Measurements column consists of arrays in string format.

I want to have a **new** `moving-average-array` column from the **past 3** measurement records, excluding those records where the `result` is 0. Past 3 records mean that for `id` 34, the arrays of `id` 31,32,33 to be used.

It is about taking the average of every 1st point, 2nd point, 3rd and 4th point to have this `moving-average-array`.

It is **not** about getting the average of 1st array, 2nd array ... and then averaging the average, *no*.

For the first 3 rows, because there is not enough history, I just want to use their own measurement. So the solution should look like this:

```
date,       id,     measure,    result .     Solution
2016-07-11, 31, "[2, 5, 3, 3]",     1,      "[2,   5, 3,   3]"
2016-07-12, 32, "[3, 5, 3, 3]",     1,      "[3,   5, 3,   3]"
2016-07-13, 33, "[2, 1, 2, 2]",     1,      "[2,   1, 2,   2]"
2016-07-14, 34, "[2, 6, 3, 3]",     1,      "[2.3, 3.6, 2.6, 2.6]"
2016-07-15, 35, "[39, 31, 73, 34]", 0,      "[2.3, 4, 2.6, 2.6]"
2016-07-16, 36, "[3, 2, 3, 3]",     1,      "[2.3, 4, 2.6, 2.6]"
2016-07-17, 37, "[3, 8, 3, 3]",     1,      "[2.3, 3, 2.6, 2.6]"
```

The real data is bigger. `result` 0 may repeat 2 or more times after each other also. I think it will be about keeping a track of previous OK `result`s properly getting those averages. I spent time but I could not.

I am posting the dataframe here:

```
 mydict = {'date': {0: '2016-07-11',
      1: '2016-07-12',
      2: '2016-07-13',
      3: '2016-07-14',
      4: '2016-07-15',
      5: '2016-07-16',
      6: '2016-07-17'},
     'id': {0: 31, 1: 32, 2: 33, 3: 34, 4: 35, 5: 36, 6: 37},
     'measure': {0: '[2, 5, 3, 3]',
      1: '[3, 5, 3, 3]',
      2: '[2, 1, 2, 2]',
      3: '[2, 6, 3, 3]',
      4: '[39, 31, 73, 34]',
      5: '[3, 2, 3, 3]',
      6: '[3, 8, 3, 3]'},
     'result': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
```

Thank you for giving directions or pointing out how to.

Comment: your measure is a str or a list of int, double quotes indicates str? and you give the possibility to delete row with 0 as result?

Comment: It is a string which you can parse and generate a list of numbers. Originally, they are floats like 3.34, 2.45. I typed in integers there for simplicity. We are not allowed to delete the rows with 0 results, we need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using only 1 for loop:

Considering the data:

```
mydict = {'date': {0: '2016-07-11',
      1: '2016-07-12',
      2: '2016-07-13',
      3: '2016-07-14',
      4: '2016-07-15',
      5: '2016-07-16',
      6: '2016-07-17'},
     'id': {0: 31, 1: 32, 2: 33, 3: 34, 4: 35, 5: 36, 6: 37},
     'measure': {0: '[2, 5, 3, 3]',
      1: '[3, 5, 3, 3]',
      2: '[2, 1, 2, 2]',
      3: '[2, 6, 3, 3]',
      4: '[39, 31, 73, 34]',
      5: '[3, 2, 3, 3]',
      6: '[3, 8, 3, 3]'},
     'result': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
```

I defined a simple function to calculate the means and return a list. Then, loop the dataframe applying the rules:

```
def calc_mean(in_list):
    p0 = round((in_list[0][0] + in_list[1][0] + in_list[2][0])/3,1)
    p1 = round((in_list[0][1] + in_list[1][1] + in_list[2][1])/3,1)
    p2 = round((in_list[0][2] + in_list[1][2] + in_list[2][2])/3,1)
    p3 = round((in_list[0][3] + in_list[1][3] + in_list[2][3])/3,1)
    return [p0, p1, p2, p3]

Solution = []
aux_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index in [0,1,2]:
        Solution.append(row.measure)
        aux_list.append([int(x) for x in row.measure[1:-1].split(', ')])
    else:
        Solution.append('[' +', '.join(map(str, calc_mean(aux_list))) + ']')
        if row.result > 0:
            aux_list.pop(0)
            aux_list.append([int(x) for x in row.measure[1:-1].split(', ')])        
df['Solution'] = Solution
```

The output is:

[image]

Please note that the result is rounded to 1 decimal place, a bit different from your desired output. Made more sense to me.

**EDIT:**

As a suggestion in the comments by @Frenchy, to deal with result == 0 in the first 3 rows, we need to change a bit the first if clause:

```
if index in [0,1,2] or len(aux_list) <3:
    Solution.append(row.measure)
    if row.result > 0:
        aux_list.append([int(x) for x in row.measure[1:-1].split(', ')])
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. This was really helpful. In fact my data is huge and very dirty. But your help cleared my way.

Comment: Hi @Silvana , good to know that it was helpful. Could you please upvote and accept my answer if you think that it deserves it?

Comment: Hi @daniel. I upvoted but the website says that it won't be visible because I don't have any reputation. To have reputation I need some upvotes they say. So, if you think that this question is a useful one for the community could you upvote the question?

Comment: Thanks anyway. But I think even without reputation you are able to accept the answer...

Comment: I really can not see anything like `accept the answer` here. I will keep checking and `accept` if the website lets me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! :) I know it sounds needy to ask for this, but at the end of the day the reputation matters.

Comment: the answer is smart, just one thing, a problem could exist if you have a 0(in Result) in one of 3 first row..

Comment: You are correct, @Frenchy. Made an edit. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) to change from a `str` of `list` to a proper `list` only the part of the data in `measure` where `result` is not 0. Use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `mean` and then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the rolling average over the last 3 rows at the next row. Then `map` to `str` once your dataframe is changed to a list of list with `values` and `tolist`. Finally you just need to replace the first three rows and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) the missing data:

```
df.loc[df.result.shift() != 0,'solution'] = list(map(str,
                              pd.DataFrame(pd.eval(df[df.result != 0].measure))
                                .rolling(3).mean().shift().values.tolist()))
df.loc[:2,'solution'] = df.loc[:2,'measure']
df.solution = df.solution.ffill()
```

Comment: Hi @Ben.T. Thank you. This really helped me a lot. Your approach is quite clean, works nicely.

Comment: The only problem I had with your solution is coming from a reason related to this entry. `eval` is not working on my large data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us

Comment: @Silvana thanks for pointing this out. I guess then using one of the solution of the link you gave to replace `eval` could do it for larger data :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
# get data to reproduce example
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(""" 
    date;id;measure;result 
    2016-07-11;31;"[2,5,3,3]";1 
    2016-07-12;32;"[3,5,3,3]";1 
    2016-07-13;33;"[2,1,2,2]";1 
    2016-07-14;34;"[2,6,3,3]";1 
    2016-07-15;35;"[39,31,73,34]";0 
    2016-07-16;36;"[3,2,3,3]";1 
    2016-07-17;37;"[3,8,3,3]";1 
    """)  

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")
df
# Out:
#          date  id        measure  result
# 0  2016-07-11  31      [2,5,3,3]       1
# 1  2016-07-12  32      [3,5,3,3]       1
# 2  2016-07-13  33      [2,1,2,2]       1
# 3  2016-07-14  34      [2,6,3,3]       1
# 4  2016-07-15  35  [39,31,73,34]       0
# 5  2016-07-16  36      [3,2,3,3]       1
# 6  2016-07-17  37      [3,8,3,3]       1  

# convert values in measure column to lists
from ast import literal_eval
dm = df['measure'].apply(literal_eval)

# apply rolling mean with period 2 and recollect values into list in column means
df["means"] = dm.apply(pd.Series).rolling(2, min_periods=0).mean().values.tolist()                            

df                                                                                                           
# Out: 
#          date  id        measure  result                     means
# 0  2016-07-11  31      [2,5,3,3]       1      [2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]
# 1  2016-07-12  32      [3,5,3,3]       1      [2.5, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]
# 2  2016-07-13  33      [2,1,2,2]       1      [2.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.5]
# 3  2016-07-14  34      [2,6,3,3]       1      [2.0, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5]
# 4  2016-07-15  35  [39,31,73,34]       0  [20.5, 18.5, 38.0, 18.5]
# 5  2016-07-16  36      [3,2,3,3]       1  [21.0, 16.5, 38.0, 18.5]
# 6  2016-07-17  37      [3,8,3,3]       1      [3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]

# moving window of size 3
df["means"] = dm.apply(pd.Series).rolling(3, min_periods=0).mean().round(2).values.tolist()
df
# Out: 
#             date  id        measure  result                        means
# 0  2016-07-11  31      [2,5,3,3]       1         [2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]
# 1  2016-07-12  32      [3,5,3,3]       1         [2.5, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0]
# 2  2016-07-13  33      [2,1,2,2]       1     [2.33, 3.67, 2.67, 2.67]
# 3  2016-07-14  34      [2,6,3,3]       1      [2.33, 4.0, 2.67, 2.67]
# 4  2016-07-15  35  [39,31,73,34]       0   [14.33, 12.67, 26.0, 13.0]
# 5  2016-07-16  36      [3,2,3,3]       1  [14.67, 13.0, 26.33, 13.33]
# 6  2016-07-17  37      [3,8,3,3]       1  [15.0, 13.67, 26.33, 13.33]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, you are including those big measurement numbers like [39,31,73,34] into your computation for finding the average. That's the problem with your solution. Look how big your averages are. It is because you included the bad results. I hope this makes it clear. Thank you.