# Turn str fractions to floats in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a really awkward pandas DataFrame that looks kind of like this:

```
identifier    per_1       per_2       per_3       per_4       per_5
'something'   124/127     100/100     24/39       14/20       10/10
'camel'       121/122     150/206     300/307     11/12       0/2
 ...          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
```

So, everything but the first column is a 'fraction' that's actually a string. I'd prefer them in decimal form. To access everything but the first column, I grab:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns != ('identifier')]
```

Which works fine. If I wanted to turn a single column into decimals, I could do:

```
df['per_1'] = df['per_1'].apply(lambda x: [float(n) for n in x.split('/')[0:2]])
df['per_1'] = df['per_1'].apply(lambda x: x[0] / x[1] if x[1] != 0 else np.nan)
```

I'd then have to iterate over every column that I want to do this for. This doesn't feel very pythonic to me, considering that I can actually grab every column that I want to do this for using `df.loc[:,df.columns != ('identifier')]`. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You can use `df.filter(like='per')`.  [pd.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter)

Comment: I need to clarify; the IDs aren't actually `('per_1', 'per_2', 'per_3', etc)`. I made a mistake of illustrating them here as though they had something in common in their names. The column names are actually more or less random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
df[['identifier']].join(df.filter(like='per').apply(pd.eval))

    identifier     per_1     per_2     per_3     per_4 per_5
0  'something'  0.976378         1  0.615385       0.7     1
1      'camel'  0.991803  0.728155  0.977199  0.916667     0
```

Comment: Maybe just `df.apply(pd.eval)`? (Not sure about the quotes in the first column though)

Comment: @RafaelC thanks :)  throws me `'unknown type str288'` any idea? ok i think its the quotes

Comment: Hm, weird..  can't reproduce. `df.apply(pd.eval)` works fine here!

Comment: @RafaelC i think the quotes is the culprit

Comment: How exactly does this work? My column names, in practice, don't have the string 'per' in them, so I'm trying to brainstorm how to modify this to work for my use.

Comment: Trying `df.loc[:,df.columns != ('identifier')].apply(pd.eval)` doesn't appear to work for me either. I get hit with `"'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'"`. No idea what that means.

Comment: @JohnRouhana your code works for me. May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us) will help you

Comment: So this works, but apparently Pandas has a bug in it; it only works up to 100 lines. I can break up what I have easily enough. Accepting answer.