# pandas column to list for a json file

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, to-json

from a Dataframe, I want to have a JSON output file with one key having a list:

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "model": "xx",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xyz",
    "categories": [1,2],
  },
  {
    ...
  },
]
```

What I have:

```
[
  {
    "model": "xx",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xyz",
    "categories": "1,2",
  },
  {
    ...
  },
]
```

The actual code is :

```
df = pd.read_excel('data_threated.xlsx')
result = df.reset_index(drop=True).to_json("output_json.json", orient='records')
parsed = json.dumps(result)

jsonfile = open("output_json.json", 'r')
data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

How can I achive this easily?

**EDIT**:

```
print(df['categories'].unique().tolist())

['1,2,3', 1, nan, '1,2,3,6', 9, 8, 11, 4, 5, 2, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9']
```

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data_threated.xlsx').reset_index(drop=True)
df['categories'] = df['categories'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split(',')] if isinstance(x, str) else '')
df.to_json('output.json', orient='records', indent=4)
```

Content of `output.json`

```
[
    {
        "model":"xx",
        "id":1,
        "name":"xyz",
        "categories":[
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

Note you can also use:

```
df['categories'] = pd.eval(df['categories'])
```

Comment: I have an error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Maybe it's due to the inconsistent data in catagories: 
I may have
- "1,2,3" 
- "1" (this one is treated like an integer)
- "" (empty)

Comment: Ok. I will fixed it

Comment: Do you test the second solution with  `pd.eval`?

Comment: yes, returning an error due to empty;
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined

Comment: Just `from numpy import nan` and retry :)

Comment: Another error :D AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'

It seems to be buggy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008191/attributeerror-pandasexprvisitor-object-has-no-attribute-visit-ellipsis-us/48008192#48008192

Comment: Ok you have more 100 records in your dataframe so `pd.eval` is useless here

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df['categories'].unique().tolist()` please?

Comment: Post Edited.  Now I have added df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

On line: df['categories'] = df['categories'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split(',')])

Comment: Can you use `[int(i) for i in x.split(',')] if isinstance(str, x) else ''` inside `apply` please?

Comment: Still not working, really struggling here :/
df['categories'] = df['categories'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split(',')] if isinstance(str, x) else '')

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union