# First name of Pandas column with sorted list

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AB': [['ab', 'ef', 'bd'], ['abc', 'efg', 'cd'], ['bd', 'aaaa']],
                   'CD': [['xy', 'gh'], ['trs', 'abc'], ['ab', 'bcd', 'efg']],  
                   'EF': [['uxyz', 'abc'], ['peter', 'adam'], ['ab', 'zz', 'bd']]})

df

               AB              CD             EF
0    [ab, ef, bd]        [xy, gh]    [uxyz, abc]
1  [abc, efg, cd]      [trs, abc]  [peter, adam]
2      [bd, aaaa]  [ab, bcd, efg]   [ab, zz, bd]
```

I want to extract the column which contains a sorted list. In this case it is **CD**, since `['ab','bcd','efg']` is sorted in ascending order. It is guaranteed that no list is empty and it will contain at least two elements. I am stuck at how to combine `applymap` and `sort` function together using Pandas ?
I tried to come up with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827199/find-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-pandas-df-which-contains-the-longest-list/45827215)  but couldn't figure out a way to combine `applymap` and `sort`.

**I am working in Python 2.7 and pandas**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `applymap` with `sorted`

```
In [2078]: df.applymap(sorted).eq(df).any()
Out[2078]:
AB    False
CD     True
EF    False
dtype: bool
```

Get result into a list

```
In [2081]: cond = df.applymap(sorted).eq(df).any()

In [2082]: cond[cond].index
Out[2082]: Index([u'CD'], dtype='object')

In [2083]: cond[cond].index.tolist()
Out[2083]: ['CD']
```

If you need specific columns with data

```
In [2086]: df.loc[:, cond]
Out[2086]:
               CD
0        [xy, gh]
1      [trs, abc]
2  [ab, bcd, efg]
```

And, get first of column name

```
In [2092]: cond[cond].index[0]
Out[2092]: 'CD'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and for filter columns `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.applymap(lambda x: sorted(x) == x).any()]
print (df)
               CD
0        [xy, gh]
1      [trs, abc]
2  [ab, bcd, efg]
```

And for column names:

```
a = df.applymap(lambda x: sorted(x) == x).any()
print (a)
AB    False
CD     True
EF    False
dtype: bool

L = a.index[a].tolist()
print (L)
['CD']
```

**Timings**

Conclusion - `df.applymap(lambda x: sorted(x) == x)` is approx. same as `df.applymap(sorted) == df`:

```
#3k rows
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [134]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: sorted(x) == x)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.08 ms per loop

In [135]: %timeit df.applymap(sorted).eq(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.96 ms per loop

In [136]: %timeit df.applymap(sorted) == df
100 loops, best of 3: 9.84 ms per loop

In [137]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: (np.asarray(x[:-1]) <= np.asarray(x[1:])))
10 loops, best of 3: 62 ms per loop
```

---

```
#30k rows
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [126]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: sorted(x) == x)
10 loops, best of 3: 77.5 ms per loop

In [127]: %timeit df.applymap(sorted).eq(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 81.1 ms per loop

In [128]: %timeit df.applymap(sorted) == df
10 loops, best of 3: 75.7 ms per loop

In [129]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: (np.asarray(x[:-1]) <= np.asarray(x[1:])))
1 loop, best of 3: 617 ms per loop
```

---

```
#300k rows
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [131]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: sorted(x) == x)
1 loop, best of 3: 750 ms per loop

In [132]: %timeit df.applymap(sorted).eq(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 801 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit df.applymap(sorted) == df
1 loop, best of 3: 744 ms per loop

In [134]: %timeit df.applymap(lambda x: (np.asarray(x[:-1]) <= np.asarray(x[1:])))
1 loop, best of 3: 6.25 s per loop
```

Comment: Interesting, can you check for `df.applymap(sorted) == df` instead of `eq`?

Comment: Yea. `eq` is the culprit, strangely.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for sortedness without sorting.

```
is_sorted = lambda x: (np.asarray(x[:-1]) <= np.asarray(x[1:])).all()
df.applymap(is_sorted).any()

AB    False
CD     True
EF    False
dtype: bool
```